# Is it ever okay to ignore a warning about an inconsistent Database schema?

Tags: database, updating

Can it ever be ok to ignore a Database schema = Inconsistent report?

The schema module is reporting the following mismatches:

contact

```
page_title: unexpected column in database
page_info: unexpected column in database
```

search_dataset

```
column type - differences on: length, default
declared: array('description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!', 'type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 16, 'not null' => TRUE)
actual: array('description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!', 'type' => 'varchar', 'length' => '64', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => '')
```

search_index

```
column type - differences on: length, default
declared: array('description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!', 'type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 16, 'not null' => TRUE)
actual: array('description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!', 'type' => 'varchar', 'length' => '64', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => '')
```

search_node_links

```
column type - difference on: length
declared: array('description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!', 'type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 16, 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => '')
actual: array('description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!', 'type' => 'varchar', 'length' => '64', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be okay, for a time, until the module that has an out of date schema attempts to read, save, update, or delete data from an out-of-date database table. At that point, you'd get inconsistent data in your database at least, and possibly end up with a corrupted database or have your site return the WSOD (white screen of death) at worst.

The warning simply means there is at least one update that hasn't yet been run. It's always a good idea to run updates by visiting update.php or using `drush updatedb` whenever you update any modules or Drupal core.

Comment: Thank you @geerlingguy
The thing is, that message is there even after a run the update.php script.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hmm. Try installing the schema module (http://drupal.org/project/schema) and see if it's report pages warn you of any mismatched tables, then edit your question and add details there.

Comment: Thank you @geerlingguy.

It's reporting 4 mismatches. Tables for which the schema and database are different: Search & Contact

contact

    page_title: unexpected column in database
    page_info: unexpected column in database


search
Show search_dataset
Show search_index
Show search_node_links

Comment: In that case, it sounds like there are some extra columns for some reason; maybe an old module you had in the past and deleted before uninstalling?

In this case, it's probably harmless to keep running the site with the mismatched schema, but it's best if you make sure you've uninstalled any modules that are no longer in use (especially before deleting them).

Comment: Thank you @geerlingguy
Is it too late for me to uninstall them now? Or will it not fix the problem?

Comment: Uninstalling the contact forms module has removed the first set of mismatches. However the search ones are still there. But when I go to my list of modules available for uninstall, there are no search related modules... :S

Comment: One way to fix the search tables would be to disable and uninstall, then re-enable search.module. I don't know how the schema would be out of sync unless one of your Drupal core updates went haywire sometime.

Comment: Thanks for that @geerlingguy.
Is there a reason why the Custom Search module would still be available in the list of Modules, even after I uninstalled it? I disabled it, uninstalled it, yet it's still appearing in the list...

Comment: Did you also delete the module out of your modules folder?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the contact module enabled?

Do you have the search module enabled?

As stated in other comments, it looks like your site wasn't re-configured properly. The correct steps for removing a module are:

1. Disable the module
2. Uninstall the module
3. For contrib modules: delete the code

The other possibility is that one or more update hooks were skipped, or run out of order. This can happen if you are running "unstable" code, like dev releases, or you had patched a module directly.

For now, it looks like none of those are fatal. No code should be trying to access an "unexpected column". In the case of the search module, each time the actual amount is larger than the declared amount. So, any code trying to use a larger value won't have any problem.